# Is there any use for basic_string<T> where T is not a character type?

Tags: c++, string

The declaration of C++ string [is the following](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

The `CharT` is character type which can be `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`; but after all `basic_string` is a template so can be instantiated with other `CharT` and other allocators. While I can think in some use cases for other allocators I'm unable to think in use cases for strings of other data types, for example:

```
using string = std::basic_string<int>;
```

Using a string of integers, we cannot initialize it as a string (obvious) nor u32 string (not that obvious, at least for me); but we can initialize it with `initializer_list` as long as the contained type of the list is convertible to `int`:

```
string err1("test");   // Error!
string err2(U"test");  // Error!
string err3{"test"};   // Error!
string err4{U"test"};  // Error!
string err5 = "test";  // Error!
string err6 = U"test"; // Error!

string success1({U't', U'e', U's', U't'});
string success2 = {U't', U'e', U's', U't'};
string success3({'t', 'e', 's', 't'});
string success4 = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};
```

But even if we manage to initialize a integer string, we cannot use it in the normal way:

```
std::cout << success1; // Error! expected 116101115116
```

The only `basic_string` expected to be used with `cout` are the *normal* ones, that makes sense: after all we cannot assume how is supposed to be printed a string of integers or a string of `MyFancyClass`es.

But anyways, the creation of *strange* instances of `basic_string` isn't forbidden; on one hand is not forbidden due to the lack of features which forbids that use (a.k.a. concepts) and on the other coding `basic_string` without limiting the underlying type is easier than doing it on the opposite way (without concepts) so, that makes me wonder:

- Is there any use for `std::basic_string<T>` where `T` is not a character type?

As for *any use* I'm thinking about things that only can be achieved with strings of `T` and that cannot be done with vector of `T` (or it will be significantly harder to do), in other words:

- Have you ever faced a situation where a string of `T` is the better choice?

Comment: Can you think of something that a string can do better than a vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver Printing?

Comment: Isnt this almost the same question as "What can you do with a `std::basic_string<char>` that you cannot do with a `std::vector<char>` ?"

Comment: A string is just a vector that is specialized for human-readable text, with overloads such as operator<< that mimic the printable character types from previous languages (BASIC, Pascal, Fortran).  So, could this question be turned around, as "Is there any situation where string<T> cannot be replaced by vector<T> with the proper overloads?"

Comment: @BoBTFish Isn't that easily fixed by adding an output operator?  The OP is asking for *things that only can be achieved with strings of T and that cannot be done with vector of T (or it will be significantly harder to do)*

Comment: @NathanOliver I was answering your question, not OPs.

Comment: @tobi303 I think that  you're right, but in the opposite way: "What can you do with a `std::basic_string<int>` that you cannot do with a `std::vector<int>`?".

Comment: I am not familiar enough to know any difference, but often it already helps to have different names for the same thing to make code more expressive. I wouldnt want to replace my `std::string`s with `std::vector<char>` even if it was the same thing

Comment: A string (in my mind) represents a sequence of characters. They may be wider than 8 bits, or consist of several 8 bit entities, like UTF-8, but still it's a sequence of characters to make up words, sentences and the like. I don't see any meaningful purpose to `string<int>` - it just doesn't "mean" anything.

Comment: @MatsPetersson soy maybe could be a good idea to limit the string underlying type to characters in the future, do you agree?

Comment: I'm guessing that it could be useful if you wanted to use array concatenation via the `+` operator, as well as string's plurality of `find_*()` functions.

Comment: Before C++11 we used `std::basic_string<_uint32>` (with `std::char_traits` specialized for it) to hold UTF32 strings. In some places we use other character traits to achieve things like case insensitive comparison or wildcard search.

Comment: FWIW in C++98 `basic_string` was guaranteed to be contiguous while `vector` was not.

Comment: @black I don't think that's true. `basic_string`'s contiguity guarantee was only added in C++11

Comment: @Barry I think I might have switched containers then. `vector` was guaranteed to be contiguous since C++03 while `basic_string` only since C++11 (as you say), although formal requirements made it essentially the only way to go.

Comment: Bool strings perhaps? But really, `vector<>` is for storage.

Comment: string is meant for things that have a semantic meaning as a whole object as well as for the individual objects.  But if `vector<T>` can do anything that `string<T>` why didn't they make `string<T>` a specialization of `vector<T>`  - there must be a reason for `string<T>` to be a separate entity.

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with a system that handles multiple text encodings (e.g. ASCII and EBCDIC), you might want a separate character type and string type for each encoding. They should both be treated as strings, but are clearly distinct types.

Comment: That doesn't seem reasonable to me, you'd have to use templates on pretty much all functions that use text then, bloating up both compile time and binary size. I'd rather go with a generic binary char string and build in switches or just use an unicode encoding internally to not have to deal with the distinctions

Answer (score 2):

When building a tokenizer, char[n] or enum comes into mind. Note that constructor of Token is not run by basic_string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

static const int max_token_length = 10;

struct Token
{
    char str[max_token_length];
};

// define std::char_traits<Token> if your implementation defaults are not fine for you (or don't exist as it's not required)

int main() {
    Token t;
    strncpy( t.str, "for", max_token_length );
    std::basic_string<Token> s1( 1, t );

    Token u;
    strncpy( t.str, "for", max_token_length );
    std::basic_string<Token> s2( 1, u );

    std::basic_string<Token> s = s1 + s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "constructor is not run"? Of course it is! Right in this line: `std::basic_string<Token> s;`, the default constructor. By the way, [according to my memory and this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) basic_string default constructor initializes it as empty instance (zero-lenght string, **unspecified capacity**). That means that s[0] **may** not exist yet, until you set it up properly.

Comment: However,aside of that, the "tokenizer" example is a good answer to the question. You can now do string-ops (concatenate/substring/etc) on strings-of-tokens ...but is it really more useful that other containers would be? I actually doubt.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl : Constructor of Token is not run (only assignment is executed), constructor of basic_string<Token> is of course executed. Editing to clarify this. You can verify this: if you add a type where assignment is invalid before constructor, it usually fails. This is (one of the reasons) why we cannot have std::basic_string<std::basic_string<char>>.

Comment: About the answer as a whole, won't you have to define a specialization of `std::char_traits<Token>` too? With an `eof` value and everything.

Comment: Why is it more useful? Because now string operations can be used on token strings! It's much more natural to write substr() or basic_string::find(), basic_string::split(), etc. than to achieve the same using iterators. In a perfect world, containers / algorithm will have all the string-like functionality and then we can have vector<> instead of basic_string<> if we preferred (I do - I prefer const version of pascal-like strings), but right now, library support is imho way better for basic_string<>.

Comment: Let's ignore the fact that `strcpy` is highly dangerous and should never, ever be used (we have `strncpy`, which is still dangerous but less so). Let's ignore the fact that you didn't specialize `char_traits` for your type. `s[0]` is required to exist, but it represents a value-initialized `charT` value (the null-terminator for regular strings). You are *not allowed* to write to the terminator value. So this is another way in which your code is wrong.

Comment: @lorro: "*It's much more natural to write substr() or basic_string::find(), basic_string::split(), etc. than to achieve the same using iterators.*" That is a matter of opinion. Also, there is no `basic_string::split` function.

Comment: s[0] always exists. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ : '(1) empty string constructor (default constructor) Constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters.' Note that capacity is not necessarily equal to length; both are size_t. operator[]() defines that, for size, it returns ref to '\0'; in C++11 this is right after the last char.

Comment: Fixing based on comments.